# Vuze Installation

Tags: vuze

I am beginner for `Ubuntu 13.04` OS. I have downloaded Vuze torrent software from Vuze wesite as a `VuzeInstaller.tar.bz2` file and saved it in my Download folder. I have extracted the folder and extracted folder name is Vuze.

How can I install `Vuze` software from the Download folder?

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install vuze`, or open Ubuntu Software Center and search for Vuze. You don't need to download Vuze from the website (and it's not particularly recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then type:

```
sudo apt-get install vuze
```

It will ask for your password, then will ask for confirmation.

Alternatively, click on the Ubuntu button (top left). Type `center` and click on Ubuntu Software Center. There's a small search bar (on the top right), type `vuze`. I guess you can continue from here.

**Remark:** These represent the *recommended* way for installing software in Ubuntu.  Most of the time you won't need to surf the web to find the software you need, just open Ubuntu Software *Center* and search for it. This is one very nice feature.

(If your default language is not English, please specify so.)

---

For an introduction to Ubuntu 13.04 read the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/). You can also visit the [Ubuntu Guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Raring) (click on [Packages](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Raring_Packages) to see an overview of how to install packages.

Comment: vuze prefers you download the software directly -- insofar as support goes.

Comment: It is not in the repositories anymore.